# bulk upload into sql

Tags: c#, sql, newline, bulkinsert

I am using this code to try and upload .csv file into sql.  It works when the path is hard coded but if I try to add a parameter result from a text box it results in the NewLine in Constant error.  What do I need to do to rectify this issue.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"BULK INSERT Alpha.dbo.Beta
         FROM  '"+FileUpload_TextBox.Text+"'
         WITH
         (
           FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
           ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
           FIRSTROW=2
         )
         ", MyConnection))
```

Comment: Kindly post the error you are getting.

Comment: the red squiggles appear under the +"' and upon hovering over it it appears NewLine Constant Error

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
FileUpload_TextBox.Text.Replace(Enviroment.NewLine,"")
```

It will remove new line chars from string

Answer (score 1):

You should never specify parameters that way. Use SQL parameters - it might solve your issue on the way:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"BULK INSERT Alpha.dbo.Beta
         FROM @FilePath
         WITH
         (
           FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
           ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
           FIRSTROW=2
         )
         ", MyConnection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", FileUpload_TextBox.Text);
    ...
}
```

If it still doesn't work, use @Garath answer when adding the parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", 
    FileUpload_TextBox.Text.Replace(Enviroment.NewLine,""));
```

Comment: When I use the above code that you first give it says underlines it in green saying it is obsolete and has been deprecated.  When I input the second code it says the 'Environment' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix the obsolete issue. About the second issue, are you sure you have `using System;`?

Comment: There are now no errors in the build but when I run the code it breaks and results in an error message saying incorrect syntax near @FilePath

Comment: Alon, this is what I was looking for.  Thanks v-much for your patience.